# get_the_date() return always UTC+0

Tags: date, timezones

I need to return correct **ISO 8601** date format for my country (Poland, Warsaw). It should be UTC+1.

I use function `get_the_date()` with argument **"c"**. On **General Settings** in field **Timezone** I chosen "*Warsaw*", but when I am using `<time datetime="<?php echo get_the_time('c') ?>"><?php echo get_the_date() ?></time>` it return e.g.: `<time datetime="2015-12-14T22:00:52+00:00">December 14, 2015</time>`.

It always return "+00:00", nevermind which timezone I use. It should be +01:00 for Poland (Warsaw timezone).

Where I made a mistake? Please, help!

Answer (score 1):

[date_default_timezone_set](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php)  can alter the output of a [new DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php). Not sure how it will affect [get_the_time](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_time).

```
$date = new DateTime( get_the_time('c') );
$date->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('Europe/Warsaw'));
echo $date->format('c');
```

---

```
$date = new DateTime();

echo $date->format('c');  

// 2015-12-18T18:21:31+00:00
```

---

```
$date->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('Europe/Warsaw'));

echo $date->format('c');

// 2015-12-18T19:21:31+01:00
```

---

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Warsaw');

$date = new DateTime();

echo $date->format('c');

// 2015-12-18T19:21:31+01:00
```